# WScript v/s CScript

Tags: vbscript, wsh, adsutil.vbs

I have query related to this topic. Here is my script. I'm using below script to edit users on `HP ILo board`, it works fine, no error at all.

BUT here I can see cmd prompt, how do I run it in silent mode, i.e I do not want to see any cmd prompt, because I use `BMC`, so let it run in background, I will check the output later.

As you said I can simply change `WScript` to `CSrcipt`. But that does not work.

Any help please, please let me know where to modify.

```
Set wshShell = WScript.CreateObject ("WScript.Shell")

WshShell.Run "cmd.exe /v:on /k (set MYDIR=C:\Program Files\HP\hponcfg) & cd /d ""!MYDIR!"" & HPONCFG.exe /f Add_User1.xml /l log1.txt > output1.txt"

WScript.Sleep 1*60*1000

WshShell.Run "cmd.exe /v:on /k (set MYDIR=C:\Program Files\HP\hponcfg) & cd /d ""!MYDIR!"" & HPONCFG.exe /f Add_User2.xml /l log2.txt > output2.txt"

Set wshShell = Nothing

Wscript.quit
```

Regards

Answer (score 1):

Use the second parameter of the [.Run](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5fk67ky%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) method

> intWindowStyle  Optional. Integer value indicating the appearance of
>   the program's window. Note that not all programs make use of this
>   information.

As I know nothing about BMC, I'd start with minimized (7, 6) before I'd try hidden (0).

Comment: hello sorry, i did not understand.  okay, forget about BMC. but what my script, silent mode??

Comment: sorry, i did not see any docs. could you please send me link again.